# Am I calling the incorrect variable to make my elif function operate correctly?

Tags: python, class

The saga of the quiz continues. After a busy couple of months I picked it up again and so far the fixes have worked. Yeah the answers automatically call the functions and it makes the point system a little messy but its easily compensated for. The problem now is my elif argument at the end, when I call the function by typing "Done" nothing prints. Even if you don't hit the points necessary to be put in one of the categories it should be printing that you're the avatar but I'm getting no output at all. That rules out me miscalculating the number of points needed to be put in a category and I know the outer functions are properly bound as I have no error flags.
I tried it with ap prefix and current code below but nothing is printing.

```
 class Benders():
      def __init__(self,firebender = 0 ,earthbender = 0 ,airbender = 0,waterbender = 0 ):
      self.firebender = firebender
      self.earthbender = earthbender
      self.airbender = airbender
      self.waterbender = waterbender

    def Firepower(self):
        self.firebender = self.firebender + 1
        return self.firebender

    def Earthbendingstyle(self):
        self.earthbender = self.earthbender + 1
        return self.earthbender

    def Windy(self):
        self.airbender = self.airbender + 1
        return self.airbender

    def Tidal(self):
        self.waterbender = self.waterbender + 1
        return self.waterbender


ap = Benders()


red = ap.Firepower()
yellow = ap.Firepower()
orange = ap.Earthbendingstyle()
green = ap.Tidal()
blue = ap.Windy()
indigo = ap.Tidal()
violet = ap.Earthbendingstyle()

yes = ap.Earthbendingstyle()
yes_o = ap.Tidal()

no = ap.Firepower()
no_o = ap.Windy()
yes = yes_o
no = no_o
    
slytherin = ap.Firepower()
hufflepuff = ap.Earthbendingstyle()
gryffindor = ap.Tidal()
ravenclaw = ap.Windy()

deer = ap.Tidal()
ram = ap.Firepower()
longhorn = ap.Earthbendingstyle()
hummingbird = ap.Windy()

cry = ap.Windy()
yell_back = ap.Firepower()
i_dont = ap.Earthbendingstyle()
try_to_understand_them = ap.Tidal()

waterbending = ap.Earthbendingstyle()
firebending = ap.Windy()
earthbending = ap.Tidal()
airbending = ap.Firepower()



def Done():
     if Benders.waterbender >= 11:
         print("'Water is the element of change. The people of the Water Tribes are capable of adapting to many things. They have a sense of community and love that holds them together through anything.' -Iroh. You are a waterbender, and this describes you to a tee. You may not neccesarily like changes but you handle it like a champ and are surrounded by steadfastfriends to get you through. Just be careful of your giving nature as some will take advantage of it.") 
     elif Benders.firebender >= 11:
         print("'Fire is the element of power. The people of the Fire Nation have desire and will and the energy and drive to achieve what they want.' -Iroh. Youre a Firebender and that is totally cool. Your determintation and cunning may scare some people,but dont let that stop you from going for what you want. The people you want in your life will be the ones cheering you on as you make it to the top.")
     elif Benders.airbender >= 10:
         print("'Air is the element of freedom. The Air Nomads detached themselves from worldly concerns and found peace and freedom. Also, they apparently had pretty good senses of humor' -Iroh. Youre an Airbender and this can be kinda contradictive. Youre the childish friend who is wise beyond your years. Most people dont know what to make of you and wish youd pick a lane...dont listen to them. Keep doing you.")
     elif Benders.earthbender >= 11:
         print("'Earth is the element of substance. The people of the Earth Kingdom are diverse and strong. They are persistent and enduring.' -Iroh. Youre an Earthbender and this comes with some negative stigma. People can see you as stubborn and maybe a bit rough but youre just protecting yourself and those you care about, still, dont be scared to be a little moveable in some areas.")
     else:
         print("You're the avatar. You are a fairly balanced individual and probably are the peacemaker in your social group and the'responsible' sibling. Make sure to take time for you, and dont forget the power you wield.")
```

Comment: Please fix the indentation. It's important that we see which code is inside the class and which is not.

Comment: `Benders.waterbender` is not correct. `waterbender` is an instance attribute, not a class attribute. So you can use `ap.waterbender` but not `Benders.waterbender`

Comment: "The problem now is my elif argument at the end" and "it isn't executing properly" are very unclear. _what specifically_ is or isn't happening? It seems like there's context that you might expect us to understand but a question on stack overflow should be a self-contained [mcve]. In order for us to offer specific answers, please [edit] to show a minimal example of the input, expected output, and a description of what is wrong with the current output

Comment: You never even call `Done()` anywhere.

Comment: BTW, you should use more descriptive method names. Methods like `Firepower()` sound like they should just return the firepower, not change it. A better name would be `IncFirepower()` to indicate that it increments it.

Comment: @Barmar please, when pointing to namind issues, take pep8 into account. A better name would be `inc_fire_power()`, but not something CamelCase which is used for class names by convention.

Comment: @SUTerliakov Since he's already CamelCasing, I suggested the minimal change, rather than going full-out PEP8. I'm more concerned with the semantics than conforming to arbitrary style standards.

Comment: @G.Anderson Fixed it up ^^

Comment: @Barmar Its suppose to be called by user by entering Done after all the questions are answered. I did the quiz as a user and nothing happened

Comment: The user calls functions directly from the REPL instead of there being a main loop that prompts for input? Then they need to enter `Done()` to call the function.

Comment: Anyway, all the `Benders.attribute` should be `ap.attribute` in the `Done()` function.

Comment: BTW, none of your variables make any sense to me. Why do you assign the result of `ap.Earthbendingstyle()` to `waterbending` instead of `earthbending`? And why do you have variables named after colors that hold these results? Is this supposed to be meaningful or are these just random variable names.

Comment: I feel like, unless there's another script doing something not shown, some/most of these things should be based around taking `input()` from the user, in the code you've posted each attribute will be incremented the exact same number of times in every run. Borrowing form your other question, it looks like you're printing questions but not taking answers, e.g., `hgwts=input('What is your Hogwarts House?'); if hgwts='slytherin': ap.Firepower()...`

Comment: @G.Anderson I had no idea you could syntax inputs that way I tried it and it worked perfectly thank you